# Calculating Signed Curvature in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curvature

Let's say we have a function $f: R^m\rightarrow R^n$, that is $n$ differentiable

How can we find the mean curvature of $f$? A more general question might be how to find signed curvature or principal curvature for an arbitrary n differentiable function in $R^n$?

Comment: Ordinarily, the way you're using the language, mean curvature and principal curvatures are only defined for oriented hypersurfaces (one dimension less than the $n$).

Comment: Assuming that now $f$ is a mapping to $R^{n+1}$ how would we calculate curvature?